# Update Recyclerview when posting a comment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-recyclerview, notifydatasetchanged

Hope you can help on this.

I have a `PostFragment` which contains a `RecyclerView` of all the posts for a thread. The idea is for the user to click on the FAB which takes them to a `NewPostActivity` which allows them to reply. How do I go about updating the adapter in `PostFragment` as I press 'post' in `NewPostActivity`.

At the moment I've tried `onResume` in the Fragment but it doesn't work. Here's my code for when I click my 'Post' button.

```
private void addPost() {

    String newPost = replaceHTMLTags(mPostMessage.getHtml());
    String threadID = PreferenceConnector.readString(getApplicationContext(),
            "threadID");
    String username = PreferenceConnector.readString(getApplicationContext(),
            "username");

    mDataFactory = new PostFeedDataFactory(this);

    mDataFactory.createNewPost(threadID, newPost, username,
            new PostFeedDataFactory.PostFeedDataFactoryCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onPostDataReceived(PostResponse response) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Posted successfully",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    finish();
                }

                @Override
                public void onPostDataFailed(Exception exception) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), exception.getMessage(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    finish();

                }
            });
}
```

And my `onResume` is basically just

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (mAdapter != null) {
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

I tried reading up on here but can't really find anything suitable to this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the posted data is inserted in the same list which is in the `PostFragment`?

Comment: Please share the code how you set the adapter and the list. I don't see the list is updated with new data. `onPostDataReceived` is not updating any list

Answer (score 1):

There is an option to create static method in your activity which will do this:

```
if (mAdapter != null) {
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

And then call it in both methods of `PostFeedDataFactoryCallback()` before `finish()`.

Also, if youre starting the second class as an activity, you can always start it as `startActivityForResult()` and then implement method `onActivityResult()` you notify the adapter for changes. In this case, what you add before each finish() is this:

```
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, your_data);
```

Look here for an example:
https://tylenoly.wordpress.com/2010/10/27/how-to-finish-activity-with-results/

Comment: mAdapter is in a different class, how could I do this?

Comment: This still confuses me, this is one of the bits i've never really done and can't get my head around it

Answer (score 0):

I don't see in the part of code where you add the new Post in the adapter.
You have to setItems and then call notifyDatasetChanged to have any effect.

If the PostFragment is in ActivityA which differs from NewPostActivity then you can use the PostFragment lifecycle to refresh the adapter by retrieving all posts as the easiest(not more efficient) solution.

Comment: But it gets added coz if I leave the fragment and then go back into it it's added to the recyclerView. My addPost method makes an API call to then add it to the database. So how would I add it to the adapter?

Comment: In PostFragment onResume you should add the code which retieves the posts from the database and set them to the adapter. So every time the fragment onResume is called, your recyclerview will be refreshed to the latest state.

An other way for communications between Views is the EventBus library, but using events for things you can do through the view's lifecycle is overuse of the library.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ways to do this, but the most efficient would be event bus. Here's an example: https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus
I suggest you better start building your apps using event bus as means of communication between activities, fragments, and event threads. This might not be the answer you're looking for but definitely a better solution.